# Looking for Example of Docusign REST API v2 Get Envelope Status Changes

Tags: rest, docusignapi

I am trying to see all of the envelopes and their status but there is no REST API Explorer for it and the example in the documentation does not work, I assume because it does not contain at least from_date. I do not see how to add the search parameters to the get request. What format should the date be in? Are the search parameters in the body of the request or somehow added to the url?

After several attempts I figured it out. Use a GET to the baseUrl/envelopes?from_date=2013-07-18&status=created for example if you wanted to see all envelopes created on or after 7/18/13 with a status of "created". I also realized that if you leave off the "status" parameter it returns all statuses except "created", so if you want to see them you have to add that parameter to the url. You MUST have the "from_date" parameter or use the "envelopeId" parameter, leaving out both will not work. You can't just search for status=completed. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen DocuSign's API Walkthrouhgs?  There's a great example of how to filter envelopes based on both the from_date and a status list.  As you've figured out, the params are added as url parameters (as opposed to params in the request body).

This API Walkthrough in particular shows how to accomplish this using a from_date of exactly one week ago from when the code is run:

http://iodocs.docusign.com/APIWalkthrough/getEnvelopeStatus

The resulting URL, if run today 7/27/13 for instance, would look something like:

https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/221765/envelopes?from_date=07%2F20%2F2013&status=created,sent,delivered,signed,completed

Notice how the URL encoded date is 7/20/2013 (i.e. one week back).